# Is there a way to make a input box have a responsive width even if its a child of flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am quite new to using flexboxes and grids and I can't quite get the hang of it, I'm trying to make a navbar with a width responsive search bar. (Kind of like the one Stack Overflow has on its navbar) but for some reason when I try and use `width: 100%` on the search bar its width does not change. I've tried looking at countless tutorials and posts and nothing seems to work. Anyhelp would be amazing

Snippet:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu+Mono&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #F4F4F5;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px #333 solid;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#searchbar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container flex">
      <h2 class="logo">Website</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <form>
            <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search.."></li>
          </form>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <button class="navbar-btn">Click me!</button>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.container nav {
  flex: 1;
}

.container form {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you climb up the **search bar** parent elements you will see that the `<nav>` element is the one taking part of the flex. So for your **search bar** to take up 100% of the width you will need to give all of his parents (`<ul>` & `<form>`) width 100%.

So something like this:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
}
form {
 width: 100%;
}
#searchbar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

To find these types of solution i would tackle it with any browser inspector such as google chromes (recommend getting there by right clicking the element itself than "Inspect"), so the inspector will jump directly to the element and climbing up and down the hierarchy and testing out the styling on the fly.

Example: [image]

*This is not the only solution. But this i feel will help you understand how to get to a solution in these kind of situations.*